# How to draw such a picture with plantUml?

Tags: plantuml

I want draw two columns in one page as shown in the figure below， How  to do this with plantUml? thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some code. Maybe another choice might be the dot program fromgraphviz?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what it is supposed to be, an UML activity diagram?
Then something like this should do the trick:

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho
(*) -down-> A
A -down-> B
B -down-> C
C -down-> D
D -down-> E
E -down-> F
F -down-> G
G -down-> H
H -down-> I
I .up........> J
A -[hidden]right-> J
J -down-> K
B -[hidden]right-> K
K -down-> L
C -[hidden]right-> L
L -down-> M
D -[hidden]right-> M
M -down-> N
E -[hidden]right-> N
@enduml
```

You may see and also try here directly online here:
http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/PSrDoeCm4CRn_NEABD-te4SGlx_r0gKB8Q66QfGOARrz4SgpoQn-3FzXuiDDrfthWkEbpJxPQHMBDifzTYKsw-ODVxT_4SZjRO9894Ze52cT8QDpv7I1WYvHqXKgkaPDDsX4UExXRoBHNW_livPIcOVLpza5rxBbHOVK3pfq37faVj2ZPp0WzuC10uCHXH-CY9MHvxfy0G00

See here for more information on the syntax: https://plantuml.com/de/activity-diagram-legacy

It isn't that accurate concerning the positions of the states yet, but PlantUML isn't really made for exactly positioning stuff.

You could also try the beta syntax for activity diagrams and try with swimlanes and hide these with skinparam parameters:
https://plantuml.com/de/activity-diagram-beta
https://plantuml-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formatting/all-skin-params.html#swimlane

Then you could either use GraphViz/Dot inside PlantUML or even directly GraphViz/Dot instead of PlantUML:
https://plantuml.com/de/dot
https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

Or just use Ditaa inside PlantUML or directly, where you have more control on positioning:
https://plantuml.com/de/ditaa
http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/